# how to inheritance multiples class through sass

Tags: sass

```
I have a scenario in sass
.A{
    background-color: red;
    Padding :20px;

    h4{ padding-bottom :20px;}
}
// another class

.B{ 
    background-color : blue; 
    padding : 20px

    h4{ padding-bottom:20px}

}
```

Question: how can i combine padding and h4 together in SASS without to repeating padding and h4 properties

Comment: `padding: 20px` _includes_ `padding-bottom: 20px`. The `h4` declaration is redundant.

Answer (score 2):

The most straight forward way is to use `@extend`.

```
%common_properties {
    padding: 20px;

    h4 {
        padding-bottom: 20px;
    }
}

.a {
    @extend %common_properties; 
    background-color: red;
}

.b { 
    @extend %common_properties; 
    background-color: blue; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You really don't save much by using sass/scss for this small of a redundancy

A solution with scss:

```
  .a, .b {
    padding: 20px;
    background-color: red;
    & h4 {
      padding-bottom: 20px;
    }
  }
  .b{
    background-color:blue;
  }
```

That solution in plain css:

```
  .a, .b {
    padding: 20px;
    background-color: red;
  }
  .a h4, .b h4 {
    padding-bottom: 20px;
  }
  .b {
    background-color: blue;
  }
```

Here is what that will look like:
http://codepen.io/cawoelk/pen/Ciqyw